# Error starting LocalStack container on Windows: Docker process returned errorcode 125

Tags: docker, localstack

I recently installed LocalStack on Windows 10, but when I ran the command:

`localstack start`

I encountered the following error:

`ERROR --- [Thread-4] localstack.utils.bootstrap: Error while starting LocalStack container: Docker process returned with errorcode 125 docker: Error response from daemon: %!L(string=is not a valid Windows path)OCALAPPDATA%!\(MISSING)cache\localstack\volume. See 'docker run --help'.`

I checked the environment variables, and LOCALAPPDATA was not present. I added it with the following directory:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local`

I restarted the system, but I am still getting the same error.

Could someone please help me figure out what is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Encountered the same issue.